Lyapunov stability of a periodic system
Consider a planar system
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=-y,\\
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=(a+\varepsilon\cos t)x,
\end{cases}
$$
where $a>0$ and $a\notin\{\dfrac{n^2}{4}\ |\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that for  $|\varepsilon|$ small enough, $O=(0,0)$ is Lyapunov stable.
Notice the system can be rewritten as
$$
\dot{X}(t)=A(t)X(t),\quad X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix},\quad A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\a+\varepsilon\cos t&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and $A(t)$ is $2\pi$ periodic. For Floquet multipliers $\rho_1,\rho_2$, it is clear that
$$
\rho_1\rho_2=\exp\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\text{tr}(A(s))\mathrm{d}s\right)=1.
$$
Therefore if $\rho_1,\rho_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, the solution is bounded.
But I have no idea to deal with the Lyapunov stability of this system. Any help is welcome!

By Floquet theorem, there exits a complex matrix $C$ s.t. $X(t+2\pi)=X(t)C$, where $X(t)$ is the fundamental solution matrix. The Floquet multipliers $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are defined as the eigenvalues of $C$.

Have you tried to construct a Lyapunov function ?

But the system is not autonomous. I have no idea about how to construct such Lyapunov function for a non-autonomous system.

In physics, you call this parametric resonance (in the context of mechanics) or a band gap (in the context of condensed matter).

@MakaBaka  It can be extended to the case of non-autonomous systems quite straightfowardly.

The construction of the Lyapunov function seems a little difficult due to the condition $a\neq\dfrac{n^2}{4}$. But I have some new idea.

For simplicity, denote $a=\omega^2$. So $\omega\neq\dfrac{n}{2}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Since $\text{tr}(A(t))=0$, by Liouville Theorem $\det(C)=1$. If $|\text{tr}(C)|<2$, it is clear that $\rho_1,\rho_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, and $O$ is Lyapunov stable. It suffices to show $|\text{tr}(C)|<2$ for above planar system.
First consider the case $\varepsilon=0$. The fundamental solution matrix of the system is
$$
X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\omega t&-\omega\sin\omega t\\
\dfrac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}&\cos\omega t
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Notice that $X(0)=I$ and $C=X(2\pi)X^{-1}(0)=X(2\pi)$. If $\omega\neq\dfrac n2,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$
|\text{tr}(C)|=|\text{tr}(X(2\pi))|=2|\cos2\pi\omega |<2.
$$
Because the solution depends continuously on the parameter $\varepsilon$, for $|\varepsilon|$ small enough it still holds that
$$
|\text{tr}(C)|<2.
$$
